# Проверка заполненности js

Tags: javascript

Есть конструкция следующего вида:

```
if (v.a > 1) {
  return 'Значение 1';
} else if (v.a <= 2 && v.b == false) {
  return 'Значение 2';
} else if (v.a <= 2 && v.b == true && v.c <= 3) {
  return 'Значение 3';
} else if (v.a <= 2 && v.b == true && v.c > 3) {
  return 'Значение 4';
} else {
  return 'Входные параметры неверны';
}
```

Если я заполню только первое поле (переменная a), и оно соответствует первому условию в if, то получу return 'Значение 1'.
Как можно корректно реализовать проверку заполненности всех полей, чтобы при пропуске хотя бы одного поля, я получал "Входные параметры неверны"?

Comment: Вам просто надо дополнительное условие, что если в объекте нет `a`, `b` или `c` то выводить ошибку или вам надо это упростить?

Comment: Чем короче получится, тем лучше :) Главное чтобы проверялось наличие значений во всех переменных.

Comment: Можете проверять с помощью [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы проверял с помощью оператора [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

- Можно проверять по одному вот так:

  ```js
  const errorMessage = 'Входные параметры неверны';

  const checkParams = (v) => {
    if (!('a' in v) || !('b' in v) || !('c' in v)) return errorMessage;

    if (v.a > 1) return 'Значение 1';

    if (v.b) return 'Значение 2';

    if (v.c <= 3) return 'Значение 3';

    if (v.c > 3) return 'Значение 4';
    
    return errorMessage;
  }

  console.log(checkParams({a: 5, b: 6})); // c not in v
  console.log(checkParams({a: 5, b: 6, c: 7})); // a > 1
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: 6, c: 7})); // v.b == true
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: false, c: 2})); // v.c <= 3
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: false, c: 7})); // v.c > 3
  ```
- А можно записать названия всех нужных полей в массив и пройтись по нему:

  ```js
  const errorMessage = 'Входные параметры неверны';

  const checkParams = (v) => {
    
    const needProps = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    
    for (const prop of needProps) {
      if (!(prop in v)) return errorMessage;
    }

    if (v.a > 1) return 'Значение 1';

    if (v.b) return 'Значение 2';

    if (v.c <= 3) return 'Значение 3';

    if (v.c > 3) return 'Значение 4';
    
    return errorMessage;
  }

  console.log(checkParams({a: 5, c: 7})); // b not in v
  console.log(checkParams({a: 5, b: 6, c: 7})); // a > 1
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: 6, c: 7})); // v.b == true
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: false, c: 2})); // v.c <= 3
  console.log(checkParams({a: 0.5, b: false, c: 7})); // v.c > 3
  ```